# Python Spidev - Argument list size exceeds 4096 bytes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Пытаюсь передать `list(img.data())` через `spidev`, но получаю эту ошибку `Argument list size exceeds 4096 bytes`. Пытался найти с помощью гугл, нужного решения не нашел. Система `Raspberry Pi` с `Raspbian.`